# Insert an element (tag) on a Page with Playwright

Tags: javascript, java, playwright, playwright-java

What is the correct way to insert a `<style>` tag into a `Page` using Playwright:

```
private void insertStyleBeforeElement(Page page, ElementHandle element, String cssContent) {
        String js = "(element, cssContent) => {" +
                "    if (!element) {" +
                "        console.log('Element is null or undefined');" +
                "        return;" +
                "    }" +
                "    console.log('Element:', element);" +
                "    let styleElem = document.createElement('style');" +
                "    styleElem.type = 'text/css';" +
                "    styleElem.innerHTML = cssContent;" +
                "    element.parentNode.insertBefore(styleElem, element);" +
                "}";
        page.evaluate(js, Arrays.asList(element, cssContent));
    }
```

This method throws:

```
com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Error {
  message='element.parentNode is undefined
@debugger eval code line 191 > eval:1:280
evaluate@debugger eval code:198:19
@debugger eval code:1:44

  name='Error
  stack='Error: element.parentNode is undefined
@debugger eval code line 191 > eval:1:280
```

Though, when I check the debugger there is a *parent* node.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

element handle's evaluate should work for you.

```
private void insertStyleBeforeElement(ElementHandle element, String cssContent) {
    String js = "(element, cssContent) => {" +
                "    if (!element) {" +
                "        console.log('Element is null or undefined');" +
                "        return;" +
                "    }" +
                "    console.log('Element:', element);" +
                "    let styleElem = document.createElement('style');" +
                "    styleElem.type = 'text/css';" +
                "    styleElem.innerHTML = cssContent;" +
                "    element.parentNode.insertBefore(styleElem, element);" +
                "}";
    element.evaluate(js, cssContent);
}
```